# Regular Expression Extractor not maintaining the variable value

Tags: regex, jmeter

Regex Extractor is working fine at first. I can get it to pull the correct value - a groupID - from the response in the previous HTTP request. And, I turn around and use the variable in the HTTP request immediately after the Extractor. That works great as well. I can see the value in the response was the same as the one placed in the post for the next request.

Few requests later I try to use the variable again when I need the groupID passed again.  But, when I look I see the default value I put in the Extractor instead of the value from the response.

My question is two fold: is this extractor only expected to generate a temporary variable?
And, if so, is there a way to plug this variable into something else for later reuse?

Or, did I just miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my mistake.  It would have helped if I read the information under the post-processor section before I read about the extractor...

I did not have the extractor as a child of the HTTP request.  I had it as the next step.

Once I nested it as a child all was right with the world.  The variable stays as it was and is not changing after every step.

Lesson learned - RTFM.  Or, at least the online documentation a bit more thoroughly!

Jamie